# Algorithm for following the path with a certain inertia

Tags: algorithm, path, line

I’m trying to develop a game.

[image: image demonstrating concept]

I have a starting point with and starting vector (blue), next I draw on screen the path (black) which I want to follow with a certain inertia, or limited angle and step each turn that should result  a red line.

Do you have any tips on how to program such algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  As you've posed your question, it's too vague to get a particularly good answer.  What specific constraints are you operating under?  What can we assume about the structure of the world?  The more detail you provide, the better we'll be able to help out.

Comment: Is black path fully available before the first move? Or, are black dots available gradually as time progresses, and red line must follow the newly revealed black dot as closely as possible? First option is preferable.

Comment: @Dialecticus I think that at least part of the black line must be available before I can start drawing a red line, however I should be able to draw red line before drawing of the black one is finished.
@ templatetypedef I can’t think of any constrains, I’m trying to simulate a flight that would follow a hand drawn path, but trying to simulate inertia (a minimum radius that object can turn around)

Comment: @Orko Is black line a moving target for a missile or car's ideal path on racing track? How do you define a success and failure of drawing a red line?

Comment: @Dialecticus I'm thinking of an airplane, it cannot turn around in a spot is has to have a minimum radius of a turn when trying to follow a black line

Comment: A missile chasing an airplane is not obliged to follow plane's path. Missile's goal is to hit the plane eventually (at any angle possible). Is this the goal of your algorithm too? To hit a moving target, regardless of the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create a differential scheme, i.e. model speed and coordinate of the source point at discrete moments in time. Say you fix some `dt = 0.1 sec` for example, starting speed is given by blue vector as `v0`. We start at `x0`.
Say `y[j]` are the points of the black path.

Let `x1 = x0 + v1 * dt`,  where `v1 = v0 + (y[k(x0)+1] - x0) * f(abs(y[k(x0)+1] - x_0))`. Where
  `k(x0)` is the index of the nearest to `x0` point among `y[j]`,
   `f(x)` is a function characterizing the 'force' pulling your trajectory to that of the defined path. It defined for nonnegative `x`es only.

This models pulling your trajectory to the next point in the defined path to that closest to current modeled position on the trajectory.

A good example of `f(x)` could be one modeling the gravitational force: `f(x) = K/(x * x)`, where `K` should be adjusted experimentally to be giving natural desired results.

Then `x2 = x1 + v2 * dt`, where `v2 = v1 + (y[k(x1) + 1] - x1) * f(abs(y[k(x1) + 1] - x_1))` and so on:

`x[n+1] = x[n] + v[n+1] * dt`, where `v[n+1] = v[n] + (y[k(x[n]) + 1] - x[n]) * f(abs(y[k(x[n])+1] - x[n]))`...

You'll have to adjust `dt` and `K` here. `dt` should be small enough for the trajectory to be smooth. Bigger `K` makes trajectory more close to defined precisely, smaller `K` makes it more relaxed.

**Edit** now actually when I thought a little bit, I understand that selection of the force function `f` was not good, as gravitational force allows space velocities, i.e. ability for your trajectory to fly away from the desired one infinitely if the initial speed is too big. So you should construct another function, possibly just something along the lines of `f(x) = K x` or `f(x) = K x ^ alpha`, where `alpha > 0`. You see, this scheme is quite general, so you should experiment.

Comment: I think that [this article](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/gdc99/) explains the same approach described in your answer but in a more hand holding way. I found it to be a very entertaining and instructive read.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to do something like this...

```
  1. Compute the average value of k points in the target path
     to get (<x>,<y>).
  2, Compte the angle between the most recent point in the path
     and (<x>,<y>) and turn that way; if the angle is too big,
     turn as hard as possible.
  3. Recompute (<x>,<y>) for the next set of k elements by sliding
     the window by 1; repeat step 2.
```

This could make for fairly appropriate behavior. I'd walk through an example, but this it would be fairly tedious. Note that this is similar to the method unkulunkulu outlines, but a little different in terms of an approach.

Comment: Good! This looks to be controllable a bit easier than mine.